# How to create an excel file in google app engine (java)?

Tags: java, excel, google-app-engine, gwt

A question that seems to have quite a few options for Python, but none for Java after googling for two days. Really really could use some help all I have found so far is a recommendation to use gaeVFS to build an excel file from the xml components and then zip it all together which sounds like a slap in the face. Oh yes and if you were wondering I am questioning my use of Java rather than python but at 5,000 lines of code it would be insane to turn back now...

Other things you might find useful

- Client: GWT
- Server: Servlets running
  on google app engine storing data
  into the google data store
- Excel file: mandatory, CSV isn't good
  enough, no need to save the file just
  to be able to "serve" it to the
  client i.e. open a "Save As" box.

Comment: I've also been trying to use the google docs api. But am having trouble "serving" an excel file once the spreadsheet is filled in. If someone can show me some sample code which serves an excel file for the user to download out of google docs I will be happy with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out this api already: [Java Excel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) ?

Comment: Looking at its use of the File class I also think it won't work on app-engine. Again would be happy to be wrong on this one.

Comment: Use Workbook.getWorkbook(java.io.InputStream is) to construct a workbook. Here comes the process:
Firstly, you can convert a string into a reader through a StringReader: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html. Then convert the reader into an inputstream: http://www.koders.com/java/fid0A51E45C950B2B8BD9365C19F2626DE35EC09090.aspx
Finally, use the getWorkbook() method aforementioned to construct your workbook.

Comment: or, there is another way to construct an inputstream:

StringBuffer StringBuffer1 = new StringBuffer("Java Forums rock");
ByteArrayInputStream Bis1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(StringBuffer1.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

This works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at the [Apache POI project](http://poi.apache.org/). You can read and write MS Excel documents with this library.

Comment: my understanding is that the libary doesn't work on google app engine. If wrong I would be a very very happy man...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this post](http://www.z80.fr/2010/03/30/google-app-engine/how-to-generate-excel-files-on-google-app-engine). 
It's a step by step tutorial on how to generate excel files on google app engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-table-to-excel/

Answer (score 0):

google app engine do not support input/output stream classes, you need to use google app engine virtual file system.